# Is my windows 8.1 still available or not ? I tried dual booting with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have been going on threads of dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. I can only boot into a live environment of Ubuntu using a LiveUSB. Without a LiveUSB, I can neither boot into Ubuntu nor Windows.

I am trying Ubuntu for the first time.

I tried Windows 10, 8, 7, XP and also Mac OSX Mountain Lion, Mavericks and Yosemite.

[image: screenshot] below. Please tell me if that screenshot looks normal or not.

Comment: donno why i need reputation to add photos ..... anyhow , the screenshot shows that i have 3 volumes sda,sda1,sda2 , sda is showing unallocated , free space and when i click on settings , everything is engraved, it is the one with windows, and the rest 2 (sda1,sda2) shows linux.

Comment: Please give output of "sudo parted -l" command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is not entirely clear to me.

But The correct procedure for dual booting is pretty simple.

First install windows in a partition. Then install ubuntu in another partition. And use ubuntu grub to access your desired operating system while booting.

And if you have done in this way, your windows partition should be fine.

Comment: I have tried all ways of dual booting and i have got tired. Currently i formatted the laptop, and installed only ubuntu 14, and am trying to use it a replacement for windows. I only use a few programs from windows for my support , so i have managed to get a few to work and the rest i am still trying. Radmin is working using wine. Exchange email working through thunderbird, now only ms lync is left, i managed to install SKY, which is like lync for ubuntu , except the lync device doesnt work on it to make phone calls, so im trying to find a way to make the device to work.

Comment: i believe you can not completely depend on linux, unless you are only browsing, and watching movies. linux is not developped profesionally hence its quite clear its not mature enough to replace windows. Windows has huge collection of quality app which simplly does not exist on linux. Dual booting is much better choise if u like linux.

Comment: i have an imac with osx yosemite, i will use that as my backup, and as for windows, i think ill try dual booting when windows 10 is out officially. I had the technical preview it was really good, then one day it just did not boot because i did not update it for a while, so i said  let me try ubuntu, which is really good so far, worked on it completely today with only 2 restarts, being a noob user of ubuntu i think it  is allright.